# differences between drawing a line or many points

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, sdl-2

I'm using C++ with SDL2 engine.

I don't understand why drawing a line with width:10000 is faster than make a loop of 10000 iterations and draw all the points that make up the line.

Drawing a line:

```
SDL_RenderDrawLine(Renderer, 0, 100, 10000, 100);
```

Drawing 10000 points:

```
for(unsigned k=0; k<10000; k++) {
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, 0+k, 100);
}
```

Why drawing all the points kills the program performance?
I think the draw_line function does the same...

I'd like to know why this because i'm trying to create some functions about shaders..

Comment: If you want to draw many points, use `SDL_RenderDrawPoints` (with the `s` at the end). I can't answer your question because I simply don't know why it is slow, but my assumption would be that there is some very expensive operations that happens at the beginning and/or end of every draw call.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez I think this, too. And that makes me sad

Comment: Like I said this could be entirely avoided by pushing points you want to render to a continuous portion of memory and then using `SDL_RenderDrawPoints` on a pointer to the first point.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez ok but i should push points 10000 times per frame. Is this slow?

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez i tried with this, but it's slow => 1fps

Comment: @DiCri if we're talking about hardware accelerated rendering, each drawing call creates overhead on both memory pressure and driver/GPU processing - that is why drawing 1 million of triangles as one call is ridiculously faster than 1 million draws. Other than that - renderer have massive paralelism and drawing only one point utilises e.g. 1/64 (for example) of execution units at *best case*. Drawing lines is expensive too (compared to triangles) but individual points will just kill performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Driver function-call overhead.  SDL_Renderer (or at least the OpenGL backend) makes no attempt to batch together multiple non-`s` calls (`SDL_RenderDrawLine()`/`SDL_RenderDrawPoint()`/`SDL_RenderDrawRect()`/`SDL_RenderFillRect()`) together, it just [calls the `s` variants with `count = 1`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/fbfacc66c65c/src/render/SDL_render.c#l1558):

```
// src/render/SDL_render.c#l1558
int
SDL_RenderDrawPoint(SDL_Renderer * renderer, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Point point;

    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    return SDL_RenderDrawPoints(renderer, &point, 1);
}
```

And the `s` functions (`SDL_RenderDrawLines()`/`SDL_RenderDrawPoints()`/`SDL_RenderDrawRects()`/`SDL_RenderFillRects()`) generally just splat out their draws to the driver [right then and there](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/fbfacc66c65c/src/render/opengl/SDL_render_gl.c#l1220):

```
// src/render/opengl/SDL_render_gl.c#l1220
static int
GL_RenderDrawPoints(SDL_Renderer * renderer, const SDL_FPoint * points,
                    int count)
{
    GL_RenderData *data = (GL_RenderData *) renderer->driverdata;
    int i;

    GL_SetDrawingState(renderer);

    data->glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        data->glVertex2f(0.5f + points[i].x, 0.5f + points[i].y);
    }
    data->glEnd();

    return 0;
}
```

A more sophisticated backend could collect geometry into larger buffers and only issue actual draw-calls to the driver when absolutely required by the API's ordering semantics.  Batching geometry and draw-calls together like that generally gives you *much* greater throughput.

Comment: i don't use OpenGL in my program

Comment: @DiCri but SDL does (or not GL but e.g. directx or metal - depends on operating system and environment, but basic idea is the same).